# Print bibliography using biber backend

Tags: bibliographies, biber

I am new with latex and i have a problem in printing the bibliography.

I exported a file `.bib` and inserted in a folder called `References`. I copy in the following line what I wrote in the main script to print the biblio.

```
\cleardoublepage

\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc, title={References}]
```

while in the preamble i wrote

```
\usepackage[style=numeric,backend=biber]{biblatex}

\RequirePackage[backend=biber, style=numeric-comp, citestyle=numeric, sorting=nty, natbib=true]{biblatex}


\addbibresource{tesi.bib}

\fi

\renewcommand{\bibname}{References}
\usepackage{hyperref}
```

Comment: Can you please describe us what the problem is? Also, what is that `\fi` for? If you don't have a good reason for it, you probably shouldn't have it there. Also, take a few minutes to elaborate a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228). Chances are you'll get a better answer if you do so :)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please add two bib entrys to your question!

Comment: The `\fi` looks out of place in the short snippet, but the situation might be different in the context of your actual document. We can only say anything useful if we get to see a short example document (a so-called MWE https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864 or MWEB https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864) that shows us in more detail (and compilably) what you are doing. It would also help if you could tell us what the exact symptoms of your problems are: What do you see, what did you expect to see instead.

Comment: For the moment I would like to mention that you probably need to run Biber on your document, i.e. a full compile cycle should run LaTeX, Biber, LaTeX, LaTeX (where 'LaTeX' can be any of your favourite LaTeX flavour: pdfLaTeX, XeLaTeX, LuaLaTeX, ...). See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864 for explanations and for help on getting your editor to run Biber.

Comment: Any news here? As it stands now your question can't really be answered properly: It is unclear. In particular it is not clear what the symptom/the undesired behaviour you are presumably asking about is. The code snippets are also not nearly enough to understand what is going on in your document (especially due to the `\fi` which seems very out of place). If there is no new development here in due time (preferably an edit to the question that clarifies what is wrong and adds a complete example document) I will vote to close this question as unclear what you are asking.